# format years bc/ac differently

Tags: java, jodatime

I would like to display e.g. 31-12-1999 for years ac and 31-12-(-)2000 for years bc.
I spent some time with the joda api's e.g. something like:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendYear(4, 10).appendLiteral("-").appendMonthOfYear(2).appendLiteral("-").appendDayOfMonth(2).toFormatter();
```

but I cannot find any details about this specific wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the AD case:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendDayOfMonth(2).appendLiteral("-")
  .appendMonthOfYear(2).appendLiteral("-")
  .appendYear(4, 10).toFormatter();
```

For the BC case:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendDayOfMonth(2).appendLiteral("-")
  .appendMonthOfYear(2).appendLiteral("-(-)")
  .appendYear(4, 10).toFormatter();
```

Then write an if statement before formatting.

If you want a single formatter to do this you can implement `DateTimePrinter` and then append that to `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.